# How to set customized data model with Flutter Slider

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a customized data model called `Item` with property `emotionLevel`, on the page, I have a list of cards that have a "Emotion Slider".

I would like to set the `Item.emotionLevel` based off the slider value, but for some reason the following code does not work (Slider stuck, can't be moved):

```
            new Slider(
                value: item.emotionLevel,
                min: 1.0,
                max: 5.0,
                divisions: 4,
                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                inactiveColor: Colors.black,
                label: 'Set a value',
                onChanged: (double newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    item.emotionLevel = newValue;
                  });
                },
                semanticFormatterCallback: (double newValue) {
                  return '${newValue.round()} dollars';
                })
```

Can someone please help point me to the right direction on how to implement a slider that able to set customized data model ? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason i can think of is that you might be initializing `Item` in your `build` method.

Remember widgets only render again when there is change in there state, i.e., simply in variables. Now, in your case Item in not initialized in  but rather in `build` function

Wrong :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Item item = new Item(); //just put it outside build
   return Scaffold(
   .
   .
   .

  }
```

Right :

```
Item item = new Item();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   .
   .
   .

  }
```

Obviously this is my guess, you can try this solution.

Comment: Thank you so so much, that it. You are straight to the point, I had my `Item` at the exactly WRONG place as you indicated.